# how to convert mat to image

Tags: c#, emgucv

I need to convert a Mat to an Image in Emgu CV.  Trying to cast a Mat to an image produces an exception: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Mat' to 'Emgu.CV.Image`

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgeOrigenal;

Capture capWebcam = null;

imgeOrigenal = capWebcam.QueryFrame();//error line
```

How can I convert the Mat to an Image?

Comment: It is nice to know that you need testet AND working code. Please remember that stackoverflow isn't a code generator. What have you tried so far to convert your Mat? Have you tried the following: *Image<Bgr, Byte> img = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();*? Its not tested but should work.

Comment: @David_D what you have done so far is what exactly i mean. this question is asked  many times but not answer correctly as you did. thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the correct answer is the first comment @David_D sent under the question.

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> imgeOrigenal = capWebcam.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In can you want to show the image in a `pictureBox` or a `dataGridView`, you can also load the image as a **Bitmap** object like this:

```
imgeOrigenal = new Bitmap(capWebcam.Bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this (and seems to work fine for all my purposes):

```
//BGR
Image<Bgr, byte> grayframe = yourMat.Clone().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();

//GRAYSCALE
Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = yourMat.Clone().ToImage<Gray, byte>();
```