# How do I take an Screenshot of my camera on EMGUCV 3.1?

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, screenshot, emgucv

I'm doing a very simple program on EMGU CV, so I need to take a screenshot of what my camera is recording and save it in a specific folder, here follows my code of camera capture:

```
        ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); 
        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(); 
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
        });
        viewer.ShowDialog();
```

> I apologize for the simple terms, I still really noob in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just posted the standard code from the EmguCV wiki. But let me try to explain how you can show a video feed of your webcam on your computer and save a screenshot when you press a button (you'll have to create all the UI elements yourself). You'll need a form with an PictureBox element to display the image and a button to save a snapshot.

I'll explain everything in the code through comments and work from the standard EmguCV code:

```
private Capture capture;
private bool takeSnapshot = false;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make sure we only initialize webcam capture if the capture element is still null
    if (capture == null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Start grabbing data, change the number if you want to use another camera
            capture = new Capture(0);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
        {
            // No camera has been found
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }
    }

    // This makes sure the image will be fitted into your picturebox
    originalImageContainer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

    // When the capture is initialized, start processing the images in the PorcessFrame method
    if (capture != null)
        Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
}

// You registered this method, so whenever the application is Idle, this method will be called.
// This allows you to process a new frame during that time.
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    // Get the newest webcam frame
    Image<Bgr, double> capturedImage = capture.QueryFrame();
    // Show it in your PictureBox. If you don't want to convert to Bitmap you should use an ImageBox (which is an EmguCV element)
    originalImageContainer.Image = capturedImage.ToBitmap();

    // If the button was clicked indicating you want a snapshot, save the image
    if(takeSnapshot)
    {
        // Save the image
        capturedImage.Save(@"C:\your\picture\path\image.jpg");
        // Set the bool to false again to make sure we only take one snapshot
        takeSnapshot = !takeSnapshot;
    }
}

//When clicking the save button
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Set the bool to true, so that on the next frame processing the frame will be saved
    takeSnapshot = !takeSnapshot;
}
```

Hope this helps you. Let me know if anything is still unclear!

Comment: Works perfect! But the button to activate the snap isn't a click, but a capacitive sensor connected to an Arduino, I don't know how I'll do that, but I do have some hypothesis. Thank you soo much, I'll have a lot of questions, but at the moment it's enough. :)))

Comment: Excuse me. That doesn't work for me. QueryFrame returns a Mat type so you can't assign it to Image<Bgr, double>.  I've tried with version 3.4.3 (using VideoCapture) and v3.1.0 as well.

Comment: @Joster if you get a Mat type, then just convert it to an image type, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34923520/7397065

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `Bgr` cannot be converted to bitmap directly. Instead I do employ
following lines:

```
 Emgu.CV.Mat capturedImage = capture.QueryFrame();
 pictureBox1.Image = capturedImage.Bitmap;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @m-öztürk - once you have sufficient reputation, you could comment on existing answers to add information such as this which is not an answer to the question but rather an improvement to the existing answer